# VueJs and Firebase

Tags: arrays, firebase, vue.js, multidimensional-array, frontend

If I have a database of

```
projects: [
{
    project_id: this.project_id,
    project_desc: this.project_desc,
    project_info: this.project_info,
    residual: this.residual,
    to_start: this.to_start,
    to_end: this.to_end,
    sections: [
    {
        section_id: this.section_id,
        section_name: this.section_name,
        section_info: this.section_info,
        contract_value: this.contract_value,
        approved_30_6_20: this.approved_30_6_20,
        approved_20_21: this.approved_20_21,
        total_approved_2021: this.total_approved_2021,
        companies: [
        {
            company_id: this.company_id,
            company_name: this.company_name,
            outgoing: this.outgoing,
            execution_rate: this.execution_rate,
            contract_value: this.company_contract_value,
        }
        ]
    }
    ],
}
]
```

And also trying to update a specific array inside this array of projects. With the code below:

```
var database = db.collection('fields')
database.where('field_id', '==', this.$route.params.field_id).get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        database.doc(doc.id)
        .update('projects', firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion.apply(null, this.projects))
        .then(docRef => {
            this.$router.push('/')
        })
    })
})
```

I have an array defined at the data() field with the name of projects, hence the use of `this.projects`. How would you suggest editing the `database.where()` statement so that I would be able to update/add - let's say - the "sections" array for a specific project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how the `project` documents are related to the `fields` collection? Also, what is the `apply()` method you use on ArrayUnion?

Comment: fields is the main array that holds the projects array. The apply method is the one turning null into the values that's in the passed array that's with it, it's a kind of a turn around another problem for the arrayUnion() method as it doesn't accept nested arrays